# How to compare one or more package codes between local and SVN repositories?

Tags: android, svn, android-studio

I change my develop environment from Eclipse to Android Studio, but i still use SVN to manage my code. And now there comes the problem:

In Eclipse, I can compare one or more package codes by this way:
"right click menu -> Compare With -> Basic Version"
And in SVN History, I can choose two version can compare to see what has changed between several versions.

But in Android Studio, I didn't find this function... What I can do is only choose one class file and do compare, but not one or more packages.

So, how can I use this function in Android Studio??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an svn client. I am not familiar with the features available or the UI, but it looks like android studio has a plugin available. Find the SVN menu and look for the feature there.

Alternatively, my preferred option is using a separate SVN client. You did not specify your operating system; TortoiseSVN is a solid and very easy client on Windows, providing a "diff with URL" command, or the ability to select revisions to compare in the log or revision graph. Other OSes have similar clients available, like RabbitVCS for Linux.

Of course, the command-line should always be available, using the [svn diff](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html) command.

Comment: Thanks, I upgrade my TortoiseSVN to v1.8 and use command line. It can't help me with this problem, but it works in other area.